# print in new line with the occurance of string using shell script

Tags: shell

I have a log file which contains warnings as shown below

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00' Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 1 Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00' Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 2 Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'

I want to print this log file as

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 1
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 2
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'

i used **cat load_bls_data.log |sed 's/\Warning/\n/g'** but i am getting output as

(Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
(Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 1
(Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
(Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 2
(Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :
cat load_bls_data.log |sed 's/Warning/\nWarning/g' ?

Here is my result:

```
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 1
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 2
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk you can do:

```
awk -v RS=' Warning ' -v ORS='\nWarning ' '1' file
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 1
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'accepted_date' at row 2
Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect date value: '2014-06-10 00:00:00'
```